# How can I make VSCode auto complete work for Terraform on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

I can't make auto complete work for .tf (and related) files with VSCode on my MacBook Pro.

Steps I took were:

- Installed the [HashiCorp Terraform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform) plugin
- Installed Terraform Language Server `brew install terraform-ls`
- Got the path:

  : which terraform-ls
  **/usr/local/bin/terraform-ls**
- And finally configured VSCode:

  "terraform.languageServer": {
  "external": true,
  "pathToBinary": "/usr/local/bin/terraform-ls",
  "args": [
  "serve"
  ],
  "maxNumberOfProblems": 100,
  "trace.server": "off"
  }

I just get the auto completion for aws items which are already in this file:

[image]

What am I missing here?
I wish those things were plug and play :(

Comment: There is a relevant known issue on the [plugin page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform#known-issues). "Completion inside incomplete blocks, such as resource "here (without the closing quote and braces) is not supported. You can complete the 1st level blocks though and that will automatically trigger subsequent completion for e.g. resource types. See relevant [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-ls/issues/57) for more."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug which has been acknowledged by the developers and is being fixed here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/issues/900#issuecomment-1011088885

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this issue, Please try the solution which worked for me-

I had got the same problem in VS code when I installed the Terraform (Anton Kulikov) extension and the version was v0.2.2. I tried many things to make my autocomplete work ,but later when I found out the solution that if you degrade your version to v0.2.1 it works.

Hope this solution also works for you- Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a workaround for this bug myself after experiencing it too. You might notice that `aws_` and `name` are highlighted. If you hit `Escape` on your keyboard, it'll cancel the selection and then autosuggestions will begin working again. Not sure of the cause, but figured out this "fix" by accident.